# material datepicker dateClass()

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using material's datepicker and ran into this problem.
material's datepicker has a method called dateClass:

```
dateClass() {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      const unvailableArray = this.shareDate.unavailableDates;
      const reservedArray = this.shareDate.reservedDate;
      let day = 'freeDate';
      for (const element of reservedArray) {
        if (date.getFullYear() === element.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === element.getMonth() &&
          date.getDate() === element.getDate()) {
          day = 'prenotation';
          return day;
        }
      }
      for (const element of unvailableArray) {
        if (date.getFullYear() === element.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === element.getMonth() &&
          date.getDate() === element.getDate()) {
          day = 'unavailable';
          return day;
        }
      }
      return day;
    };

  }
```

this method is located within the appCmponent.ts, allows me to color the calendar cells by cycling a list of date arrays and is invoked in the appComponent.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Clicca sul calendario</mat-label>
    <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="this.shareDate.myFormattedDate" (dateChange)="openDialog($event)">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass()" #picker> </mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

what I would need is for this method to be called inside another component in order to update the cell coloring.
how can I do? I tried to import appcomponent.ts inside the second component trying to invoke dateClass () but it doesn't work.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to call this displayClass() method within another component, the best practice will be to move this method from app.component to somw shared service and pass this.shareDate as an argument so you can use it within any component you want it to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the method to some shared serivce say shared.service.ts

```
dateClass(shareDate : any) {
return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
  const unvailableArray = shareDate.unavailableDates;
  const reservedArray = shareDate.reservedDate;
  let day = 'freeDate';
  for (const element of reservedArray) {
    if (date.getFullYear() === element.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === element.getMonth() &&
      date.getDate() === element.getDate()) {
      day = 'prenotation';
      return day;
    }
  }
  for (const element of unvailableArray) {
    if (date.getFullYear() === element.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === element.getMonth() &&
      date.getDate() === element.getDate()) {
      day = 'unavailable';
      return day;
    }
  }
  return day;
}
```

Now you can use this method from app.component and any other component you want to, like

in .component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Clicca sul calendario</mat-label>
<input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="this.shareDate.myFormattedDate" (dateChange)="openDialog($event)">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass()" #picker> </mat-datepicker>
```

in component.ts

```
dateClass(){
 return this.sharedService.displayClass(this.shareDate);
}
```